# Facebook c# sdk Fork: Version5 oAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, fork, facebook-c#-sdk

First, please excuse me because i speak english like a french cow!

This is it, i have decided to get off the Facebook Toolkit and start to use the Facebook c# sdk.

I looked at the v4.2.1. Then i read "http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=241181" and i downloaded the v5 source code.

I've got a little problem with the auth process with this V5.
Here is my code:

```
    string _requiredAppPermissions = "offline_access,email";
    FacebookApp fbApp = new FacebookApp();
    var fbSettings = new FacebookSettings();
    fbSettings.AppId = RWE.Core.Config.FacebookApp;
    fbSettings.AppSecret = RWE.Core.Config.FacebookSecret;
    Authorizer authorizer = new Authorizer(fbSettings);
    //Authorizer authorizer = new Authorizer();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_requiredAppPermissions)) authorizer.Perms = _requiredAppPermissions;
    authorizer.Perms = _requiredAppPermissions;
    authorizer.ReturnUrlPath = _AuthUrlReturn;
    authorizer.Authorize();

    var me = fbApp.Api("me");
```

So if i load the app from the url : "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp", it displays a facebook logo with (in french) "Accéder à Facebook" (which means 'access to facebook'). The link is kind of "http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=170580299646394&method=permissions.request&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&response_type=code&fbconnect=1&perms=offline_access%2Cemail"
If i load the app from "http://realurl.com", it displays directly the authorisation form like it should be in the facebookapp url.

My questions are :

1. How can i have the auth form displayed directly (without the facebook logo step) ?
2. While i specify a ReturnUrlPath, facebook still uses facebook.com/connect/login_success.html and leads me to facebook.com instead of going back to the app. How can i change that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you specify **target="_top"** for your <a> tag.

```
<a href="..." target="_top" />
```